# contact form popup goes behind the slider

Tags: html, css, forms

i have created a simple popup contact form with following form elements

- name
- email
- phone number
- subject
- message

when i click the popoup form it goes behind the slider images and i have created this form as html file and used a php include in footer.php file

please refer the image below

[image: images]

and following code have been used

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Include Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    /* Additional CSS for Popup */
    .popup {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      right: 20px;
      bottom: 20px;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
  
    .popup-content {
      background-color: #fefefe;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #888;
      width: 100%;
    }
  
    .close {
      color: #aaa;
      float: right;
      font-size: 28px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  
    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* Additional CSS for Popup Button */
    .popup-button {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 20px;
      right: 20px;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 8%;
      height: 7%;
      font-size: 14px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    /* Additional CSS for Success Message */
    .success-message {
      display: none;
      margin-top: 20px;
      color: green;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    /* Additional CSS for Form Fields */
    .form-group {
      position: relative;
    }

    .form-control:focus {
      border-color: #80bdff;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
    }

    .error-message {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      color: red;
      font-size: 14px;
      margin-top: 4px;
    }
    
    .btn-primary {
      background-color: #0055A5 !important;
      border-color: #0055A5 !important;
    }
    
    .btn-primary:hover {
      background-color: #0055A5 !important;
      border-color: #0055A5 !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Button to open the popup -->
  <button class="btn btn-primary popup-button" onclick="openPopup()">Contact Us</button>

  <!-- The popup -->
  <div id="myPopup" class="popup">
    <!-- Popup content -->
    <div class="popup-content">
      <span class="close" onclick="closePopup()">&times;</span>
      <h2>Contact Us</h2>
      <form method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
          <span class="error-message" id="nameErrorMessage"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
          <span class="error-message" id="emailErrorMessage"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
          <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required>
          <span class="error-message" id="phoneErrorMessage"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" required>
          <span class="error-message" id="subjectErrorMessage"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message">Message:</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
          <span class="error-message" id="messageErrorMessage"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <p class="success-message" id="successMessage">Email sent successfully!</p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Include Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Function to open the popup
    function openPopup() {
      document.getElementById("myPopup").style.display = "block";
    }

    // Function to close the popup
    function closePopup() {
      document.getElementById("myPopup").style.display = "none";
    }

    // Function to validate the form
    function validateForm() {
      var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
      var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
      var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
      var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
      var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
      var isValid = true;

      // Validate name (should not be empty)
      if (name === "") {
        document.getElementById("nameErrorMessage").textContent = "Please enter your name.";
        isValid = false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("nameErrorMessage").textContent = "";
      }

      // Validate email (should not be empty and should have a valid format)
      if (email === "") {
        document.getElementById("emailErrorMessage").textContent = "Please enter your email.";
        isValid = false;
      } else if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
        document.getElementById("emailErrorMessage").textContent = "Please enter a valid email address.";
        isValid = false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("emailErrorMessage").textContent = "";
      }

      // Validate phone number (should not be empty and shouldhave a valid format)
      if (phone === "") {
        document.getElementById("phoneErrorMessage").textContent = "Please enter your phone number.";
        isValid = false;
      } else if (!isValidPhoneNumber(phone)) {
        document.getElementById("phoneErrorMessage").textContent = "Please enter a valid phone number.";
        isValid = false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("phoneErrorMessage").textContent = "";
      }

      // Validate subject (should not be empty)
      if (subject === "") {
        document.getElementById("subjectErrorMessage").textContent = "Please enter the subject.";
        isValid = false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("subjectErrorMessage").textContent = "";
      }

      // Validate message (should not be empty)
      if (message === "") {
        document.getElementById("messageErrorMessage").textContent = "Please enter your message.";
        isValid = false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("messageErrorMessage").textContent = "";
      }

      // Form is valid, send email
      if (isValid) {
        sendEmail(name, email, phone, subject, message);
      }

      return isValid;
    }

    // Function to validate email format
    function isValidEmail(email) {
      var emailPattern = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
      return emailPattern.test(email);
    }

    // Function to validate phone number format
    function isValidPhoneNumber(phone) {
      var phonePattern = /^\d{10}$/;
      return phonePattern.test(phone);
    }

    // Function to send email using PHP
    function sendEmail(name, email, phone, subject, message) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", "send-email.php", true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
          showSuccessMessage();
        }
      };
      var data =
        "name=" + encodeURIComponent(name) +
        "&email=" + encodeURIComponent(email) +
        "&phone=" + encodeURIComponent(phone) +
        "&subject=" + encodeURIComponent(subject) +
        "&message=" + encodeURIComponent(message);
      xhr.send(data);
    }

    // Function to show the success message
    function showSuccessMessage() {
      document.getElementById("successMessage").style.display = "block";
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

created the popup form as index.html and placed the as php include in footer.php

i.e

`<?php include 'form/contact-popup.html';?>`

Comment: Try a different https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: in mobile it is not working

Comment: We don't seem to have a [mre] of the issue. I see your popup, I see some CSS, I see a lot of irrelevant Javascript about validating the form (which has nothing to do with how it displays), but I don't see anything about a slider. If the problem is how it interacts with the slider, then we need to see an example with it all together, so we can understand the specific problem. We cannot guess why they are not happy together, when we can only see one half of the pieces. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. We'll be happy to help, once we have all the necessary info. Thanks.